# cmake build protobuf error: NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND'

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

this's my project tree:

```
proto-build
     |—— build/           #empty, used for cmake building
     |—— include/
           |—— google/      #protobuf headers
     |—— lib/
           |—— libprotobuf-lite.lib
     |—— proto/
           |—— test.proto
     |—— CMakeLists.txt
```

this's CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

SET(ROOT_PATH ".")
SET(PROTO_DIR ${ROOT_PATH}/proto)
SET(PROTOBUF_LIBRARY ${ROOT_PATH}/lib)
SET(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR ${ROOT_PATH}/include)


find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${PROTO_DIR}/test.proto)
add_library(foo ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
target_link_libraries(foo ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

then I open cmd and locate to proto-build/build/, run command:

```
cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

it works fine. then run command:

```
nmake
```

errors occurred:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'E:\Source\proto-build\PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program_Filesx86\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Program_Filesx86\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protobuf's executalbe is not found. Thus the wrong path `E:\Source\proto-build\PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND` is written into the Makefile and this errors out.

Comment: thx so much for your help, I have worked it out from your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

thx for usr1234567's suggestion, I have figure it out, this's new CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

SET(ROOT_PATH ".")
SET(PROTO_DIR ${ROOT_PATH}/proto)


#must define these tow variables:PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR & PROTOBUF_LIBRARY, even the value is invalid. 
SET(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR .) 
SET(PROTOBUF_LIBRARY .) 

SET(PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE ../protoc.exe)

#in this directory, contains protobuf includes: top directory is <google>
SET(THIRD_INCLUDE_DIR ${ROOT_PATH}/include)

#if set PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR to the directory of protobuf includes instead of using include_directories, errors occurred when nmake,I don't know why
include_directories(${THIRD_INCLUDE_DIR})

file(GLOB PROTO_LIST ${PROTO_DIR}/*.proto)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${PROTO_LIST})
add_library(foo ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
target_link_libraries(foo)
```

use this CMakeLists.txt to camke and nmake, building will be success.
there're several details need to pay attention, I have comment in CMakeLists.txt.

**there's a strange issue**: you must place two protoc.exe files in directory:one is in proto-build/, and one is out of proto-build/, otherwise an error would occurred: not found protoc.exe.